# Update user profile is not working when click the update button in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, angular6

We are using Angular with Node.js Express.We try to update user details from settings page but when click the update button it throws:

**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**
It seems can't send an update through the observable. When I check this URL in Node:
**http://localhost:3000/api/chatapp/user/edit-user** It says **{"message":"No Authorization"}** in the browser. Here is the code.

**Angular**

```
  EditUser(body): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${BASEURL}/user/edit-user`, body);
  }
```

**TS**

```
private populateForm() {
    const unusedFields = [
      '_id',
    ...
    ...
    ];

    const userInfo = Object.assign({}, this.user);
    unusedFields.forEach((field) => delete userInfo[field]);
    this.SettingsForm.setValue(userInfo);
  }

  private buildSettingsForm() {
    this.SettingsForm = this.fb.group({
      email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email], this.forbiddenEmails],
      firstName: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')]],
      jobTitle: [null, [Validators.required]],
      lastName: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')]],
      username: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])')]]
    });
    this.SettingsForm.setValidators(this.minimumAge(18));
  }

  UpdateUser() {
    this.usersService.EditUser(this.SettingsForm.value).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.router.navigate(['main']);
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

Also **Node.js**:

```
async EditUser(req, res,next) {

User.findById(req.user.id, function (err, user) {

  if (!User) {
    return res
    .status(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    .json({ message: 'User is not found' });
}

  const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    username: Joi.string()
      .min(4)
      .max(10)
      .required(),
    email: Joi.string()
      .email()
      .required(),
      firstName: Joi.string().required(),
      lastName: Joi.string().required(),
      jobTitle: Joi.string().required(),
  });

  const { error, value } = Joi.validate(req.body, schema);
  if (error && error.details) {
    return res.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({ msg: error.details })
  }

const email = Helpers.lowerCase(req.body.email);
const username = Helpers.lowerCase(req.body.username);
const firstName = req.body.firstName;
const lastName = req.body.lastName;
const jobTitle = req.body.jobTitle;

User.email = email;
User.firstName = firstName;
User.lastName = lastName;
User.username = username;
User.jobTitle = jobTitle;

User.update()
});
} 
}
```

**Router**

```
router.post('/user/edit-user', AuthHelper.VerifyToken, UserCtrl.EditUser);
```

**MongoDb**

```
    const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      username: { type: String },
      email: { type: String },
      isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
      password: { type: String },
      passwordResetToken: String,
      passwordResetExpires: Date,
      firstName: { type: String },
      lastName: { type: String },
      jobTitle: { type: String },
...
...
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I think something is wrong in both Node.js controller and in Angular function. What is wrong? How can we fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

did you send the token with the request ?!

you've forget to construct the schema

```
    const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      username: { type: String },
      email: { type: String },
      ...
   )}
```

to catch the error you might pass a callback as an argument to save function.

```
user.save(function (err, updatedUser) {
    if (err) {
        /* Handle the error */
    };
 });
```

you might use set `user.set({ [key]: value });` instead of direct access by dot notation e.g `user.firstname`

in your situation it will be like

```
user.set({
        email: email,
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        username: username,
        jobTitle: jobTitle
})
```

your final code will be

```
async EditUser(req, res, next) {
    User.findById(req.user.id, function (err, user) {
        if (!user) {
            return res
                .status(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .json({ message: 'User is not found' });
        }
        const schema = Joi.object().keys({
            username: Joi.string()
                .min(4)
                .max(10)
                .required(),
            email: Joi.string()
                .email()
                .required(),
            firstName: Joi.string().required(),
            lastName: Joi.string().required(),
            jobTitle: Joi.string().required(),
        });
        const { error, value } = Joi.validate(req.body, schema);
        if (error && error.details) {
            return res.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({ msg: error.details })
        }
        const email = Helpers.lowerCase(req.body.email);
        const username = Helpers.lowerCase(req.body.username);
        const firstName = req.body.firstName;
        const lastName = req.body.lastName;
        const jobTitle = req.body.jobTitle;
        user.set({
            email: email,
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            username: username,
            jobTitle: jobTitle
        });
        user.save(function (error, updatedUser) {
            if (error) {
                /* Handle it */
            }
        })
    });
}
```

you can read more about in mongoose documents for more details

> [Update mongoose document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating)

as note, in `populateForm` method you can filter the object upon the `unusedFields` array without use **`delete`** keyword

Comment: I use AuthHelper.VerifyToken which checks it that user has permission to do so. At the same time, other operations are working like uploading image posting something. Only above EditUser throws the error.

Comment: i suppose that you already intercept the request and bind the **`Authorization: 'Bearer youreToken'`** header with it.

since **`EditUser`** doesn't response with **`{"message":"No Authorization"}`**, the **`AuthHelper.VerifyToken`** already doing

if you use the old **http** you need to set the header with each request 

    return this.http.post(`${BASEURL}/user/edit-user`, body, {headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`}});

Comment: So how can this be fixed? As I said all other functions are working like posting or uploading an image, even changing the password. Only this one causes trouble I think something is wrong in the above code.

Comment: use **`user`** instead of **`User`**

then call `user.save();`
not `user.update();`

Comment: it was with the user and save in the past but throwing an error of can't set email of null and the user couldn't found so there were lots of errors because of that and I changed User and update. Also save is not defined :D

Comment: `user.save(function (err, updatedUser) {
    if (err) { /* Handle the error */ };
  });` you can catch the error like this.

you might use set
`user.set({ [key]: value });`
instead of direct access by dot notation

read the doc for more details
[update document mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating)

Comment: If it's not difficult for you can you please explain it on the above my question's code example by copying the code in your answer? such comments are making people a bit confused.

Comment: According to your answer, it looks you explained first 2 options in the documentation. So which parts should I remove in my Node.js example and start with user.set?

Comment: both of them must work
i have update the answer, please take a look again

Comment: Should I just replace it with user.update() or above parts of my code must be removed as well?

Comment: Please forgive about the above comment
set it just set the new value, and save who make the decision to update the value

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and sorry for asking so many questions but it throws error again. If I use user.set it says can't set of null if I use User.set it says set is not a function.

Comment: as i said you forget to construct the schema, use `new mongoose.Schema`